# Print dataframe to console during intermediate steps in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

While debugging dplyr chains in a function, I often want to be able to print intermediate changes to a data.frame to the console. How would I do this?

For example:

```
data(cars)
cars %>% group_by(speed) %>% 
  summarize(dist_mean = mean(dist)) %>%
  [insert printing function] %>% 
  group_by(speed > 10) %>%
  summarize(dist_mean = mean(dist_mean)) %>%
  [insert printing function]
```

Is there something I can do to replace `[insert printing function]` to print the current state of the dataframe to the console, while still continuing the chain uninterrupted?

Comment: you might be interested in `tidylog` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidylog/readme/README.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the T-pipe: `%T>%`.

From documentation:

> Pipe a value forward into a function- or call expression and return the original value instead of the result. This is useful when an expression is used for its side-effect, say plotting or printing.

There is a good example of it [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/09/the-four-pipes-of-magrittr/) along with the other two less common pipe commands.

Inserting back into your original context:

```r
data(cars)
cars %>% group_by(speed) %>% 
  summarize(dist_mean = mean(dist)) %T>%
  print() %>% 
  group_by(speed > 10) %>%
  summarize(dist_mean = mean(dist_mean)) %T>%
  print()
```

**Edit:** As per @Ritchie Sacramento's comment the pipes are part of the magrittr package. They also appear to be re-exported by dplyr. If they don't work after calling `library(dplyr)` then you will need to call `library(magrittr)` to access them.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Unless users click on your link, they may not be aware that `%T>%` is a `magrittr` function rather than a `dplyr` one.  You can improve your answer by specifying the necessary library calls.

Comment: Thank you Ritchie. All four pipes are re-exported by the dplyr pacakge. So developers can write `library(dplyr)` or `library(magrittr)` to use them. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: That's not correct I'm afraid - `dplyr` only exports `%>%`.  Try a fresh session and load only `dplyr` and you'll see or take a look at `?dplyr::reexports`.

Comment: Hmm... that is odd. I have just tested it and successfully used `%T>%` after only calling `dplyr`. I have even checked and confirmed that the magrittr package is not loaded. Perhaps the documentation and the reexport are not in-sync?

Comment: @Simon.S.A. - not sure but my guess is that when testing your session was not completely clean.  You can look at the source code `https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/R/utils.r` and see that `%>%` is the only magrittr export.